# What is recommended for Google Apps Script to try to automate emails? I tried, but what happened was that there was an error function?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function MyFunction() {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();

var n=sheet1.getLastRow();

for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {

var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();

var name=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();

var ServiceAcquired=sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();

var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

message=message.replace("<name>",name).replace("<service>",ServiceAcquired);

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}

}
</script>
```

I tried to run, but the same problem resulted every time: there was a function error.

Comment: What's the error you get with this code? - [edit] the question and add the error details

Comment: I get the problem function not found: doGet on Google Apps Script.

Comment: I tried to use VS code and link the drive spreadsheets with the https, but no email was received.